# How to add VM options to jar file?

Tags: java, jar, virtual-machine, executable-jar

I need to add `-Djava.security.policy=myPolicyFile` so that my RMI jar would work. Or is there some other way to make that run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wanting to add the -D when someone launches your jar using `java -jar`, that's not possible because it's not possible to specify JVM options inside the jar:

[Can I set Java max heap size for running from a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file)

That said, if you're in control of the process, you could use `java.security.Policy.setPolicy` to manage the policy object yourself.

Comment: got this in my code:
if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
        {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
        }
should i add it there?

Comment: Do i have to use external policy file? Can i just put it in code?

Comment: No, there is no public API (that I'm aware of) for converting a policy file into a Policy object.  You need to subclass java.security.Policy and properly implement getPermissions(CodeSource) to grant permissions to relevant code sources.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html) on how to use policy files. If you are using netbeans or some other IDE, you should be able to add

> -Djava.security.policy=myPolicyFile

as an option to your VM, which is usually found somewhere within the project's properties.

Comment: Yes, I know - got it in netbeans already but the problem is to get the same effect in jar.