# How to create an executable jar file with 1 GB heap

Tags: java, jar, executable

I created a class that gives a text file containing system performance as output. I want to run it as an **executable** Jar. but when I run the Jar I want to increase the heap to 1 GB.

If we run this program I can do this by running like this:

```
java -Xms1200m  -Xmx1300m Sample
```

But how can I increase heap space using an **executable** Jar? When I click on the jar it must execute with a heap space of 1 GB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set Java max heap size for running from a jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 java -Xms1200m -Xmx1300m -jar FILENAME.jar
```

Define this somewhere in the jar File or in the Manifest is not possible:

[Can I set Java max heap size for running from a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file)

Comment: i want to set up heap space for an executable jar

Comment: Then check out the link in this answer. It is not possible with just a jar, you need some wrapper (shell script, web start, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned: it unfortunately is not possible (without creating a wrapper, whether shortcut/script/executable ...).

If you're only running on Windows, I can recommend [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to create an executable wrapper that can apply these settings on execution:

Wrapping it in a executable has other benefits:

- If a suitable version of Java is not found, it will prompt the user to download it
- Windows 7 Start Menu will treat it properly (highlighting it as a new application after installation)
- Windows Firewall will treat it properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>PATH_OF_YOUR_JAR</jar>
  <outfile>PATH_OF_YOUR_EXE</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine>-log_file=logs\\hp</cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <customProcName>true</customProcName>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>PATH_OF_THE_ICON</icon>
  <singleInstance>
    <mutexName>APPLICATION_NAME</mutexName>
    <windowTitle></windowTitle>
  </singleInstance>
  <jre>
    <path>jre-w32\</path>
    <minVersion></minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <initialHeapSize>512</initialHeapSize>  
    <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

It is a launch4j Config file, here you can specify the heap size as per your requirement.