# Increase Heap size for a executable jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I created a executable jar file using eclipse, It requires 5gb of heap size depends on excel size which it processing, i can increase heap size of that program in eclipse run configuration and run successfully but after exporting it as executable jar file heap size set to default heap size and i unable to complete the task. How i can export the jar file with eclipse heap size setting itself.

Thanks
Suriyan

Comment: It seems that this is currently not possible. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879661/how-to-create-an-executable-jar-file-with-1-gp-heap

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018217/can-i-set-java-max-heap-size-for-running-from-a-jar-file

Comment: A good idea from 1018217 seems to be to start a small Java program when the jar is executed which will then start the "real" program with the heap size setting (and other arguments passed down from the parent, if any).

Answer (score 0):

Go to envirentment variables make a new key called "JAVA_OPTS"
Value should be
-Xmx 5024m