# How to set Java parameters when using an executable Jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable

When using an executable JAR file, I have run into some issues related to memory and language.

To work around the memory issue and language issue, I have found that any required values can be preset by setting the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable on that specific machine.

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms128m -Xmx256m -Duser.language=en
```

Instead of having to visit each and every possible client, is it possible to set the configuration within the executable JAR file so that when the JAR is execute, it is done so using the specific configuration?

Comment: Please refer [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193483/how-to-specify-jvm-argument-for-maven-built-executable-jar)

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Distribute runnable script (in form of .bat .cmd .sh file) and you will be able to set required environment vars there.

Another option is to build native executable wrapper and specify java params there, eg https://www.jwrapper.com/